# Server peek by Own-IP-Calls?

Tags: images, links, server-load

My site did not load a few times in the past day so I contacted my webhost and asked for a reason - their answer revealed, that Own-IP-Calls were the reason for the increased traffic.

As far as I know, Wordpress always links to images and internal links via absolute links.

Is that a common problem? Are there any fixes despite using a cdn?

Answer (score 0):

Absolute URLs are not the reason for your problems. Relative and absolute links stress servers the same way.

There can be a problem if you load all your content at once (e.g. hundred of images).

You can solve this issue with AJAX (loading content on demand).

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: @s t thanks for your help! I found out that my website loaded ~10 different stylesheet per page which I now combined and as my site is image heavy I switched to a CDN - so my server is a lot less busy! But your idea would be another solution!